# How to get total value of checkboxes and pass it on second page

Tags: jquery

I have made some calculation using jquery in Page1.html by getting the

value from inputboxes using get function and set the values in inputboxes

by using set function. I also want to get the total amount of value of

checkboxes if check all, but i am getting the value of only one checkbox.I

also want to pass the total value of checkboxes to page2.html in

inputbox13. kindly help me out.

```html
Page1.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get a time-based greeting:</p>
INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput" value="">
DEDUCTION: <input type="text" id="myinput1" value="" readonly>
GROSS INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput2" value="" readonly>
TAX: <input type="text" id="myinput3" value=""readonly>



NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput4" value="">

<button id="click1">CALCULATE NET INCOME</button><br><br>

NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput5" value="">

<label>SELECT MENU:</label>
<select class="fee">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="3000">3000</option>
  </select>

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="1500" >1500 FOR MALE

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="1000" >1000 FOR FEMALE

<input type="radio" name="gender" value="500" >500 FOR OTHER

<input type="checkbox" name="car1" value="10000" >INVESTMENT ONE

<input type="checkbox" name="car1" value="20000" >INVESTMENT TWO

<input type="checkbox" name="car1" value="30000" >INVESTMENT THREE

AGRI INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput6" value="">
OTHER SOURCE: <input type="text" id="myinput7" value="">
TOTAL INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput8" value="">

<button id="click2">CALCULATE TOTAL INCOME</button>

<button id="click3">next</button>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#click1").click(function a(){
        
  myfunction();
        
    });

   
function myfunction() {
var tax, tax1, tax2;
var inc = $("#myinput").val();
 alert(inc);
  $("#myinput1").val(10000);

  tax1 = inc - 10000;

  $("#myinput2").val(tax1);
     
     if (tax1 <=250000) {
        tax = "0";
     } 
 
 else if (tax1 >250000 && tax1<=500000) {
 tax = (tax1 - 250000)*5/100;
  }

 else if (tax1 >500000 && tax1<=1000000) {
 tax = 12000 + ((tax1 - 500000)*20/100);
  }

 else { tax = 112000 + ((tax1 - 1000000)*30/100);
  }

 $("#myinput3").val(tax);
 

 
 
 tax2 = tax1 - tax;
 

 $("#myinput4").val(tax2);
 $("#myinput5").val(tax2);
  
 
}

 $("#click2").click(function b(){

     
  myfunction1();
        
    });
 function myfunction1() {
var tax4, tax5, tax6, tax7, tax8, tax9, tax10, tax11;
 
 var ni=$("#myinput4").val();
 var fee = $(".fee").val();

 var rd =  $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();

 var ck = [];
            $.each($("input[name='car1']:checked"), function(){            
                ck.push($(this).val());
                });
alert(ck);
 var tax4 = $("#myinput6").val();
 var tax5 = $("#myinput7").val();

a=parseInt(fee);
n=parseInt(rd);
o=parseInt(ck.join(", "));
m=parseInt(ni); 
k=parseInt(tax4);
l=parseInt(tax5);
 tax6 = k + l + m + n + a + o;

 $("#myinput8").val(tax6);  

 $("#click3").click(function c(){
  window.location.href="getset-index2.html?tax7="+$('#myinput8').val()+"&tax8="+$('#myinput4').val()+"&tax9="+$(".fee").val()+"&tax10="+$("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
 });

 }
 

});
</script>

</body>
</html>

Page2.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>


<body>
TOTAL INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput9" value="" readonly>
NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput10" value="">
FEE: <input type="text" id="myinput11" value="">
PANELTY: <input type="text" id="myinput12" value="">
INVESTMENT: <input type="text" id="myinput13" value="">
EMI CAR: <input type="text" id="myinput14" value="">
TOTAL NET INCOME: <input type="text" id="myinput15" value="">

<button id="click4">CALCULATE NET INCOME</button><br><br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    tax9 = urlParams.get('tax7');
    tax10 = urlParams.get('tax8');
    tax11 = urlParams.get('tax9');
    tax12 = urlParams.get('tax10');
    tax13 = urlParams.get('tax11');
    $("#myinput9").val(tax9);   
    $("#myinput10").val(tax10);
    $("#myinput11").val(tax11); 
    $("#myinput12").val(tax12);  

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("#click4").click(function d(){
 

   myfunction2();
 });
  function myfunction2() {
   
var tax11, tax12, tax13;

 var gettax9 = $("#myinput9").val();
 var gettax10 = $("#myinput10").val();
 var tax12 = $("#myinput14").val();

 x=parseInt(gettax9);
 y=parseInt(gettax10);
 z=parseInt(tax12);

 tax13 = x + y + z;

 $("#myinput15").val(tax13);

}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code is not working. The script unable to calculate the value.

Comment: did you try the answer below?

Comment: Yes i have tried. After trying this code click2 is not working. Unable to give the calculated answer.

Comment: "not working" isn't an error message or problem statement we can work with. Did you try to debug your code using the browser's Developer Tools, and therefore get some proper information about the issue (e.g. error messages, unexpected variable values, other unexpected behaviour, details of which lines of code specifically (in your very large code sample) are causing difficulty)?

Comment: Yes i have tried but did not get anything. Can you do something to run this code correctly.

Comment: You should have got something if you did it properly. Step through the code line by line in the debugger, and check what path the code takes and what values the  variables have. and keep going until you find something you don't expect. That will help us to narrow down the problem. It's a vital skill you need to learn if you want to succeed in programming

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the function `myfunction1()` in the line

```
o = parseInt(ck.join(", "));
```

This would only give you the first integer value and would skip all integers after the comma.

Use this code instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ck.length; i++) {
  if(!isNaN(ck[i])) {
  o += Number(ck[i]);
  }
}
```